# How can I convert a case class to a lift-json jobject class?

Tags: json, scala, lift

I have a case class

```
case class Doc(title:String, ....)
```

which I want to convert to a lift-json `JObject`so I can more easily use `JObject` methods merge, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Extraction.decompose(Doc("foo", ...))
```